# $h^2=(2\sqrt[3]{2})^2 - (\sqrt[3]{2})^2$. h should be equal to $\sqrt[6]{108}$ but I get $\sqrt[6]{4}$ as a result. Please help.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

My resolution
$${\quad \quad \quad(2\sqrt[3]{2})^2 = h^2+(\sqrt[3]{2})^2 \\ 
\iff ( \sqrt[3]{16})^2= h^2 + \sqrt[3]{4} \\
\iff \sqrt[3]{256} = h^2 + \sqrt[3]{4}\\
\iff h^2 = \sqrt[3]{256}- \sqrt[3]{4}\\
\iff h = \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{256}- \sqrt[3]{4}} = \sqrt[6]{256}- \sqrt[6]{4}\\
\iff h = \sqrt[6]{64\times 4}- \sqrt[6]{4}\\
\iff h = 2\sqrt[6]{4}-\sqrt[6]{4} = \sqrt[6]{4}}$$

I've tried it over and over again but always get the same result. But in the textbook it says it should be $\sqrt[6]{108}$ .

Comment: in your third last line, you take the sqare root of a sum and equal it to be the square root of each summand. Thats no equality! E.g. take $5=\sqrt{25}=\sqrt{9+16}=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}\neq 3+4$ It also doesn't hold for your specific numbers. (Which you can check in a calculator)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{256}-\sqrt[3]4}\ne\sqrt[6]{256}-\sqrt[6]4.\;$  Cf. [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream)

Comment: By the difference of squares, $h^2=(2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{2})(2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{2})=\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot3\sqrt[3]{2}$...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Since $h^2=3\sqrt[3]{4}$, $h^6=3^34$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are wrong in 6th line.

$$h=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{256}-\sqrt[3]{4}}\ne\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{256}}-\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{4}}$$

The correct way to do this,
$$h{=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{256}-\sqrt[3]{4}}\\
=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{4^3\cdot4}-\sqrt[3]{4}}\\
=\sqrt{4\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{4}}\\
=\sqrt{3\sqrt[3]{4}}\\
=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{4\cdot3^3}}\\
=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{108}}\\
=\sqrt[6]{108} \quad \square}$$

Or, simply you can do,
$$h^2{=(2\sqrt[3]{2})^2 - (\sqrt[3]{2})^2\\
=\left(2\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}\right)(2\sqrt[3]{2} - \sqrt[3]{2})\\  
=\left(3\sqrt[3]{2}\right)\cdot(\sqrt[3]{2})
\\=3(\sqrt[3]{2})^2\\}$$

$$\therefore h=\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt[3]{2}=\sqrt[6]{3^3\cdot2^2}=\sqrt[6]{108}$$

Comment: Best answer. Thank you so much. Another comment before pointed out that: $$h=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{256}-\sqrt[3]{4}}\ne\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{256}}-\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{4}}$$. But didn't explain why or what to do instead. Then someone responded why it was wrong but I didn't quite get it. Now with the alternative resolution I understood it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notice that we sort of have "like terms" on the left-hand side:

\begin{aligned}
h^2 &= (2 \sqrt[3]{2})^2 - (\sqrt[3]{2})^2 \\
&= 4 \sqrt[3]{4} - \sqrt[3]{4} \\
&= 3 \sqrt[3]{4}
\end{aligned}

If we want to write this as one root -- that is, without anything in front -- we have to "unsimplify" the $3$.  In particular, it can helpful at this stage to use fractional exponents rather than roots, since the rules for combining them are more direct.  But in order to add fractional exponents, we need a common denominator:

$$ 3 \sqrt[3]{4} = 3^{3/3} \cdot 4^{1/3} = (3^3 \cdot 4)^{1/3} = 108^{1/3}$$

Now since it was $h^2$ that equaled $108^{1/3}$, we have $h = \pm (108^{1/3})^{1/2} = \pm 108^{1/6} = \pm \sqrt[6]{108}$.  Apparently, your book wants the positive answer :).